# Fetching the meta title of a Facebook profile through PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I'm trying to fetch the meta title of a website through the PHP function below.
It works for all websites but Facebook, I'm getting this this error:

> "Update Your Browser | Facebook"

```
function fetchMeta($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

$header = array();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlX);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$sites_html = fetchMeta("https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange");
echo $sites_html;
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your user agent with it, right now as it's blank (or cURL's default)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Proper user agent string, maybe your browsers?");
```

Facebook is detecting you are using an unsupported/old browser as it's not able to detect a modern user agent.

Comment: I tried using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36");` but Facebook still returns the same error: `Update Your Browser | Facebook`

Comment: Facebook may be implementing another style of check with this (possibly Javascript based?) that is simply not being ran by cURL (and hence displaying this error).  The only other exhaustive option I can recommend is looking up exactly what headers you yourself send to Facebook on the first load, and duplicating those within cURL.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
// Fetching the meta title of a Facebook profile through PHP
ini_set("user_agent","facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"); // EXTRA
function fetchMeta($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // EXTRA
$header = array();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] = "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// EXTRA
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://facebook.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // SSL TRUE or FALSE
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
// EXTRA
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$sites_html = fetchMeta("https://www.facebook.com/albdroid.official"); //Albdroid Test <Working OK>
//$sites_html = fetchMeta("https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange");  // stackexchange Test <Working OK>
echo $sites_html;
?>
```